# Using SharedPreference to save data permanently how could i add the data to an ArrayList

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPreference to save data (String) that been choose in ListView from  activity(A), each time only the one been choose,and been save by SharedPreference and the plan is to read and to show this data (and all the older one that been choose in the past) in activity(B) in a listView.

How could I save and add each time the one been chosen and keep all the older to save that like ArrayList, to add each time the new to a ListView of all the history that been choosen?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the SQLite database instead of SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use SharedReference you have to create 2 methods converting and deconverting your data (to\from String), e.g.:

```
static final String UNIQUE_SPLIT_VALUE = "<|>";

String arrayListToString(List<String> list) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (String value : list) {
        result.append(value);
        result.append(UNIQUE_SPLIT_VALUE);
    }
    return result.toString();
}

List<String> stringToArrayList(String prefString) {
    return Arrays.asList(prefString.split(UNIQUE_SPLIT_VALUE));
}
```

...

```
saveToPreferences(arrayListToString(myDataList));
myDataList = stringToArrayList(getDataFromPreferences());
```

Another way you can achieve the same results - serialize\deserialize your data to\from file.